# Llenar array en PHP con formulario y mostrar resultados en una tabla

Tags: php, html, formularios

El problema que tengo es el siguiente, tengo que realizar una plataforma de gestión financiera y para ello me piden que cree las variables que son, $fecha, $concepto, $cantidad y $saldo. La fecha sera un campo por defecto, el concepto y la cantidad serán los datos que introduzca el usuario y el saldo será un campo calculado.
El problema es que para estas variables me piden crearla en un array multidimensional el cual deberé rellenar con el formulario. 
He mirado el manual de PHP pero no consigo llegar a ninguna solución para esto...
Muchas gracias de antemano a todos!!

Comment: No queda claro lo que quieres. Necesitas que en PHP se definan como Array? O quieres que en el formulario cuando des a submit envíe los datos como Array?

Comment: intenta hacerlo como en el [ejemplo 6 del manual](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php#example-103)

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que necesitas, simplemente pones esto en un bloc de notas, lo guardas con extension `.PHP` en la carpeta que ejecuta los archivos del servidor APACHE, lo ejectuas con algún emulador de apache, yo utilizo [WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

```html
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
Fecha:
<input type="text" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" disabled>
<input type="text" name="info[fecha]" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" hidden>
<br>
Concepto:
<input type="text" name="info[concepto]" required>
<br>
Cantidad:
<input type="number" name="info[cantidad]" required>
<br>
Saldo:
<input type="text" name="info[saldo]" required>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
<?php 
//comprueba si la variable info es creada si es que el formulario es enviado
if(isset($_POST['info'])){
$array=$_POST['info'];
$fecha=$array["fecha"];
$concepto=$array["concepto"];
$cantidad=$array["cantidad"];
$saldo=$array["saldo"];
echo "Los valores obtenidos en el formulario con Array Multidimensional es:<br>Fecha:".$fecha."<br>Concepto:".$concepto."<br>Cantidad:".$cantidad."<br>Saldo:".$saldo."";
}
?>
```

Comment: serías tan amable de explicar tu código, lee [answer] no es solo colocar el script además debes explicarlo